# Pass a value from parent directive template to child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:**

I'm attempting to pass a value from an ng-repeat into a child-directive but when I try to access my passed variable in directive 2 I get "undefined".

Here's an illustration of what I am attempting. Basically **directive 1** represents an array of widgets while **directive 2** represents a single widget. I am attempting to pass an item from the ng-repeat loop into my child directive.

[image]

**My Attempt:**

Here's a simplified version of my **directive 1** template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in widgets">
    <directive2 item="item"></directive2>
</li>
```

Here's a simplified version of **directive 2**:

```
angular.module('directive2').directive(
    ['$compile', '$rootScope',
    function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        return {
        restrict: 'E',
            scope: { item: '=' },
            templateUrl: 'ext-modules/tile/widgetTemplate.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
                console.log(scope.item); // undefined
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The ng-repeat on **widgets** creates two items and I have verified that the data exists. The application works fine and doesn't throw an error but my console.log returns : undefined.

### My Question:

How can I pass a value from a directive template's **ng-repeat** into a child-directive?

---

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3znEu/112/

Comment: the code you posted should not log undefined. try it in a plunkr.

Comment: thanks, @rob, I'm attempting to assemble a jsFiddle now

Comment: Why are you asking about **ng-if** if you're using **ng-repeat**? Also, is creating module named 'directive2' really intended? Can you create jsfiddle that presents your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another solution proposal:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <directive1></directive1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.widgets = [
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
    ];
   }])
.directive('directive1', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    template: 
      '<li ng-repeat="item in widgets">' +
        '<directive2 item="item"></directive2>' +
      '</li>'
  }
})
.directive('directive2', ['$compile', '$rootScope',
  function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { item: '=' },
      template: 
        '<div>elem = {{item}}</div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        console.log(scope.item);
      }
   }
}]);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/dfn75sp3/

Answer (score 2):

It works fine when you put `directive2` as directive name, not `module`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3znEu/113/

```
      'use strict';

       var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.greeting = 'Hello World!';
            $scope.widgets = ["111","222","333"]
        }]);

        app.directive('directive1',
            ['$compile', '$rootScope',
            function ($compile, $rootScope) {
                return {
                restrict: 'E',
                    scope: { item: '=' },
                    template: '<div>{{item}}</div>',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
                        console.log(scope.item); // undefined
                    }
                };
            }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddler a bit http://jsfiddle.net/3znEu/115/.
 Few changes
1. Added a restrict to your directive.
2. Added a template to render the Items (only for testing and demo)
3. Changed items in scope from '@' to '='

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("directive1", function(){
return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {

  item: "="
},
template: "{{item}}"
}
});
```